# calling wtforms from sqlalchemy in flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm building a website that has several survey forms.

```
class A(Form):
    name = Text('Name')

class B(Form):
    name = Text('Name')

class C(Form):
    name = Text('Name')

etc...
```

I have a model that holds information on all these forms:

```
class forms(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    wtform = ???db.Column(db.String(255))??? # How to store a wtform [A, B, C, etc...]?
```

From a menu a user would select a particular form and be directed to:

```
@app.route('/new/<int:id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new(id):

    data = forms.query.get(id)

    form = data.???wtform???  # How to call the particular wtform here?
```

I'm not sure how to store and call a wtform class from sqlalchemy. What is the best method to deal with this sort of situation? Should I instead use multiple @app.route('/A'), @app.route('/B'), @app.route('/C') calls for each form, which would increase redundancy,   or could I store the entire wtform class structure in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You already define the forms in your code, so there's no reason to store them in the database as well.  Store a reference to which form to use, then just instantiate the correct form based on the reference.

```
class FormDef(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'form_def'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False, default='')
    form_ref = Column(String, nullable=False)  # will be the name of the form class in this example

def get_form(instance):
    # given an instance of FormDef, get the form class with the name stored in form_ref
    from my_package import forms  # or wherever your forms are stored

    return getattr(forms, instance.form_ref)
```

On a side note, storing form class information in rows does not seem like the right way to solve whatever it is you're trying to solve.